# Network disabled, how to fix this?

Tags: 16.04, networking

I have formated my laptop, wireless is not detected.

```
    *-network               
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:98200000-98203fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 88E8072 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:86:00.0
       logical name: ens5
       version: 00
       serial: 00:25:b3:42:05:5c
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2 driverversion=1.30 duplex=full ip=192.168.0.13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:30 memory:90100000-90103fff ioport:2000(size=256) memory:90120000-9013ffff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: 00:21:00:b2:16:48
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=b43 driverversion=4.4.0-116-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
```

This is what I have tried so far.

```
sudo ip link set ens5 up

mm@6830s:~$ iwconfig
ens5      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

But it does not work.

```
sudo iwlist wlp3s0 scan
[sudo] password for mm: 
wlp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down
```

This my interface

```
/etc/network/interfaces 
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto ens5
iface ens5 inet dhcp

Edit


       lsmod | grep hp
hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
hp_accel               28672  0
lis3lv02d              20480  1 hp_accel
shpchp                 36864  0
wmi                    20480  1 hp_wmi
mm@6830s:~$ sudo modprobe -r hp-wmi
[sudo] password for mm: 
mm@6830s:~$ lsmod | grep hp
hp_accel               28672  0
lis3lv02d              20480  1 hp_accel
shpchp                 36864  0
```

No improvement,I can not turn on wireless.

[image]

Button goes back to off immediately. Why?

My laptop is HP6830s, Ubuntu 16.04.
My boot options

[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work? Your output indicates to me that the hardware adapter is being detected and used correctly by the kernel. Did you try to scan for wireless networks? `sudo iwlist wlp3s0 scan`

Comment: @thomas.mc.work take a look at my edit,please!

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: rfkill list all

Comment: @chili555 I have added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have installed the wrong driver. Let's fix it. With a working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel source
wget https://media-cdn.ubuntu-de.org/forum/attachments/04/32/2480236-Broadcom_Firmware.tar.gz  
sudo tar xvf 2480236-Broadcom_Firmware.tar.gz -C /lib/firmware/
```

Reboot. If the wireless is not working as expected, please run:

```
rfkill list all
```

Is the hard block fixed?

**EDIT**: HP laptops use a module *hp-wmi* to translate key presses into action; in your case, turn off the hard block and turn on the wireless.

Let’s troubleshoot your problem.

First, and most obvious, look around your laptop and find the wireless switch and switch it. On some laptops, it may be called ’Airplane Mode.’ After you switch it, check again:

```
rfkill list all
```

Is there any change?

If not, check to see if the module *hp-wmi* is loaded.

```
lsmod | grep hp
```

If so, remove it:

```
sudo modprobe -r hp-wmi
sudo rfkill unblock all
rfkill list all
```

Any improvement?

Comment: No,take a look driver iswl,I can not purge bcmwl.

Comment: If you wish to use the correct driver b43 and its firmware, it will be necessary to purge bcmwl-kernel-source.

Comment: Take a look at my edit,still the same.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: New edit,please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the `Secure Boot` from the boot menu sometime you won't be able to use the external hardware like wifi or graphics because of secure boot in a dual booted system.

After this go in the software update window make sure you are connected to the wired connection for fetching the additional `proprietary driver`.
within few minutes you can see the `proprietary driver` in that windows choose to use that driver and reboot system.

Comment: Take a look at my edit,I have old comp it does not have secure boot.

Comment: are you able to see any `proprietary driver` in use in software update window?

Comment: It didn't work with bmcwl,I have deleted this driver.

Answer (score 0):

I entered `sudo lshw -c network` to discover my network Logical name was different from that within interfaces so:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Enable edit mode replaced `eth0` with `ens32` .

```
sudo service networking restart
```

or

```
sudo ifdown --exclude=lo -a && sudo ifup --exclude=lo -a
```

This allowed me to start the network without an error, and I'm guessing the name may have changed because I did a release upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04, then 14.04 to 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

these commands worked for me

```
sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```